# How do I access a resource in my WAR directory with Jetty?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

How do I access a file in my war directory from a servlet. For example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    // how do I load /war/html/page.html
}
```

That file path is relative to my project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got me what I was looking for:

```
req.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/html/page.html")
```

...where req is the `HttpServletRequest` object passed into the servlets doGet or doPost method.

Answer (score 0):

html pages are usually statically served, no servlet needed. (well, technically, no servlet by *you* is needed, as its functionality provided by the "default servlet" of your web container)

just try hitting your deployed webapp in a browser.

```
http://{machine}:{port}/{app-context}/{path-in-war}
```

It would be good if you read some [basics on servlets and webapps in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html), it'll go a long way to answering these sorts of basic questions.

Comment: I know it seems like the kind of question that thrown out there without looking for a solution myself, but that's not the case. The documention is dense and couldn't find the answer after looking around for a good while. Maybe this is what I'm looking for: `req.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("html/page.html")`